# What does it mean to "fit a regression function" and then use it to update other functions?

Tags: regression, logistic, boosting

Referring to the algorithm on page 11 in [this paper on boosting algorithms](http://bcmi.sjtu.edu.cn/~zhzhang/papers/multiclass.pdf), I really don't understand step 2, (ii) and (iii).

What does this mean:

> (ii) Fit the regression function $g_j^h (x)$ by weighted least-squares of
>   the working response $z_{ij}$ to $x_i$ with weights $w_{ij}$ on the training
>   data.
>
> (iii) Set $g_j(x) \leftarrow g_j(x) + g_j^h (x)$

For convenience, I'm pasting the algorithm here:

[image: gentleboost.c]

I do understand the theory and general concept of least squares regression. I understand we have data whose graph doesn't have a clear line or curve formula, and so we try to come up with a function that'll help us predict a response given an input. Using "least-squares" means coming up with a formula whose parameters are such that the square of the errors of the prediction is minimized.

But once this regression function is "fitted" to data, how is it "added" to other functions like itself?

I'm having a hard time understanding the application of the above quoted statement. Not just in this algorithm, but in others, wherever they mention "fitting" a regression function and then using that function with others. At best I understand using regression functions to actually predict values as output. But how do we use them to predict/generate more functions?

Could someone please explain this simply, maybe using arrays of data or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to notice that you not use in this algorithm the "least-squares", but "weighted least squares". See [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least%5fsquares#Weighted%5fleast%5fsquares) dedicated to this matter.

The main distinction is that instead of the usual:
$$LSE(y, \hat{y}) = E[(y - \hat{y})^2] = E[(y-\hat{f}(x, \beta))^2]$$
you have an additional factor
$$WLSE(y, \hat{y}) = E[(y - w\hat{y})^2] = E[(y-w \hat{f}(x,\beta))^2]$$
where $w$ comes from weights. In the standard weighted least squares, weights have some properties, to be able to get a BLUE estimator. In your case the weights are the current weights computed at step $(i)$.

Now you have also to note that at step $(b)$ the predictor for the current step $g_j(x)$ is altered by adding previously fitted predictors. Note that the formula from the $(b)$ step can be decomposed as a linear combination of other functions. Which means it has the form:

$$g(x) = \beta_0 + \beta_1f_1(x) + \beta_2f_2(x) .. + \beta_pf_p(x)$$

where $\beta_i$ are constant factors, and $f_i$are functions of input variables.

Thus, in the end, the final computed $g_j(x)$ will be a linear combination of the fitted function at step $j$ and all other previously fitted predictors.

This qualifies the final $g_j(x)$ to be an additive model since an generalized additive model is a linear combination of other predictors.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Just to be absolutely sure I'm on the right track, just want to make a few clarifications: **(1)**
y = true response, **(2)** y^= predicted response from our regression function f(x,β), **(3)** E[...] = expectation/mean  
**(4)** and let's say that the first iteration, our regression function is g1(x) = 3x + 4, and in the second iteration, it's g2(x) = 5x -1, then at the end of the second iteration, we'll have g(x) = 8x + 3.  
Have I got it all right?

Comment: 1. If m=2, than for your case you have $g_2=\frac{m-1}{m}[g_2-\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}g_i]=\frac{1}{2}[5x-1 - \frac{1}{2}(5x-1+3x+4)] = \frac{1}{2}[5x-1-\frac{1}{2}(8x+3)]=\frac{1}{4}[2x-7]$1.

2. I made a mistake, instead of $\hat{f}(x,\beta)$ I typed without hat. I will correct that. 

Agree with all the other things.

Comment: But I just noticed, in step 2(c), for computing $β_j(X_i)$, what is $g_{ci}(X_i)$?

Comment: At step $(a)$ are fit $m$ prediction vectors, one for each target class. At step $(b)$ the prediction vectors are smoothed, so that each prediction vector will take into account what the others prediction vectors "have to say about that". This is why is called "gentle", the changes are not aggressive.
Now, you need one $\beta$ for each class. The formula for $\beta$ "incorporates" also knowledge about which is the target value. In fact if you notice, both formulas are the same, since if $j=c_j$ the $g_j(x_i)-g_{c_j}(x_i)=0$.

Comment: thanks a lot you explained step (b) very well but the question asked in the above comment was about going from step (a)(ii) to (iii). How can I do $g_j(x) + g_j^{(h)}(x)$? Let's say that on iteration $j=1$, from step (ii), I got $g_1(x) = 3x + 4$ by fitting the function to $x_1$. Then let's say when $j=2$ in the next iteration, I fit the regression function on $x_2$, and I get $g_2(x) = 5x -1$. Then how does step(iii) work now? How can I do $g_2(x) + g_j^{(h)}(x)$? Will this be $(3x + 4) + (5x - 1)$ to make $g_2(x) = 8x + 3$?

Comment: the answer is yes (to your last question)

Comment: Thanks to all your help, I've been able to code the algorithm. But I have one issue. In step (2)(ii), is the algorithm really saying that the regression function should be determined for $x_i$, where $x_i$ is one observation, out of the full set of observations $X$? In other words, let's say that $X$ is a 2D array, where each row, $x_i$ represents one observation, and the number of columns is the number of dependent variables/regressors per row.Does that mean we need to find the regression function parameters for a single row? Does WLS regression for one observation exist?http://bit.ly/1m22GGG

Comment: No, the regression will be performed on the whole data set, with current weights and regress on current residual $z$, then you compute the fit values, which are the prediction of the model on the data

Comment: I have a conceptual question about the final result. I'm using this classifier for 2 classes. When the response vector $z$ & the $weights$ are 1D arrays, then the parameters of $g(x)$ are also a simple 1D array, and the prediction is easy, it gives a single value as a result. But if $z$ and the weights are 2D arrays, and the final $g(x)$ is a 2D array, then giving in a test observation and getting its prediction results in an array of two values, and not a single value. What do these 2 values correspond to? Is this result giving me a "prediction score" per class?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the pestering but I've completed the code and was wondering if you could give a few minutes to run through it, and let me know if it's actually according to the published algorithm or not? 
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/48992/compare-code-with-documented-algorithm-is-this-correct

Comment: I do not understand Python. However, as far as I understand, $g(x)$ is always a matrix with $n$ rows ($n$ number of instances/data points) and $m$ columns ($m$ being the number of classes). So, for a binary classifier, $g(x)$ should have 2 columns. My understanding of $g$ is that it will contain a probability mass function, $g_j(x_i)$ being interpreted as "the probability of data point $x_i$ being classified as class $c_j$".

Comment: Follow-up question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96579/understand-the-parameters-for-multiple-regression-question-based-on-the-notati